# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument Ошибка в коде для автоматизации нажатия инлайн кнопки

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

пару часов пытался сделать бота для автоклика на инлайн кнопку в определенном чате, но ничего не вышло.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest

api_id = 123456789
api_hash = '000000000000000000000000000000'

session_name = 'main'

with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    request = GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(peer='тут юзер чата', data['тут айди сообщения'], data='inline_button_data')
    result = client(request)
```

Результат:

> SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Или возможно кто-то очень добрый и с достаточным количеством свободного времени может написать мне такое, на любой библиотеке? :(

Comment: Не получается в **telethon**, пробуй **pywinauto**.

Comment: @DiMithras ошибки синтаксиса исправляются не заменой модуля, а исправлением самой ошибки

Comment: чтобы заменить себя ботом нужен интеллект превышающий бота

Comment: хорошо сказано!

Comment: @insolor согласен, но и альтернативные решения можно рассмотреть. Я, например, **telethon** не знаю, а на **pywinauto** пальцы натасканы.

Comment: @ganz ну почему же, есть [RPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation), тыкаешь в no-code блоки, много ума не надо 

Comment: это работает в фоновом режиме? через апи тг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    request = GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(peer='тут юзер чата', data['тут айди сообщения'], data='inline_button_data')
                                          ^^^^^                 ^^^^

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Перевожу для вас: позиционный аргумент следует за именованным аргументом. У вас первый аргумент именованный `peer=`, а второй нет. Питон такое не понимает. Если я правильно понял [документацию на бот](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_bot_callback_answer.html), ваш второй аргумент должен называться `msg_id=`.

```py
    request = GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(peer='тут юзер чата', msg_id='тут айди сообщения', data='inline_button_data')
                                                                ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо, синтаксическая ошибка решилась, но теперь новая: NameError: name 'data' is not defined. Это в msg_id=data

Comment: А, ну там видимо просто id сообщения откуда-то. Это вам виднее, откуда у вас взялось `data['тут айди сообщения']` вообще, есть ли у вас такая коллекция `data` )

Comment: Точно, сам не понимаю к чему там вообще дата, но заменив ее на просто msg_id = '123' то уже ошибка с короутином. sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.__call__' was never awaited. Я искал решение этой проблемы и в каком-то треде было написано что просто перед вызовом надо добавить await, но ничего не получалось

Comment: `await` сам по себе не бывает, посмотрите где-то полный пример кода. Там `event loop` какой-то должен быть и т.д.

Comment: вообщем пересмотрел я все примеры, везде только пару строк с вызовом этой функции только в разном виде, перепробовал и успеха это тоже не принесло(

Comment: В общем, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос про это. На тот вопрос, который вы задали изначально, я ответил. А это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: спасибо и на этом) 